# How $this->Paginator can be called?

Tags: php, cakephp, properties, cakephp-2.x

Please consider the code fragment bellow. How can $this->Paginator be called if its not a class attribute?

```
class PaginasController extends AppController 
{
    public $components = array('Paginator');
    public $paginate = array(
            'limit' => 5,
            'order' => 'Pagina.modified DESC',
            'fields' => array('Pagina.id', 'Pagina.title', 'Pagina.created', 'Pagina.modified')
        );

    public function index() 
    {
        $this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;
        $paginas = $this->Paginator->paginate();
        var_dump($this->Paginator);
        $this->set(compact('paginas'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`PaginasController` extends `AppController`

`AppController` extends `Controller`

The method `loadComponent()` in the `Controller` class does the trick of adding the property to the controller. See the API [**here**](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/source-class-Cake.Controller.Controller.html#304-325)

> `loadComponent( string $name , array $config [] )`
>
> Add a component to the controller's registry.
>
> This method will also set the component to a property.

In cake 2 the same task is performed by `ComponentCollection` class in the `init()` method [**here**](https://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-ComponentCollection.html#39-55)

Comment: Actually, its Cakephp 2.4. There is no loadComponent()

Comment: I edited, but always remember to name your cake version in the question